# Как настроит php на cors

Tags: php

Впервые работаю с react, пытаюсь отправит запрос на свой сервер из react приложении но сервер не отвечает:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как я понял необходимо настроит сервер на `cors`, `backend` у меня на `opencart` использую [советы добрых людей](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8719276/cors-with-php-headers) не помогает пишу в скрипт:

> header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');
>
> header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET, POST');
>
> header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers: X-Requested-With");

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

как быть? как разобраться?

Comment: так заголовки пишутся перед выводом. А в начале файла  **вне класса** что по-вашему должны они делать?

Comment: Даже так не работает, невозможно отправит запрос, сервер в глухую отказывается ответит, я думал настроит cors на сервере так как здесь: `https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8719276/cors-with-php-headers` говорится что функция  `heade()` в помощь.

Comment: второй скрин - это ведь вы просто в браузере открыли адрес на который идет запрос из приложения? что прислал в ответ сервер на запрос именно из приложения?

Comment: @Skywave да именно, т,е запрос идет по этому адресу: `http://yunuso2c.beget.tech/?route=extension/aliexpress/home/homerecommend`

Comment: что прислал в ответ сервер на запрос именно из приложения?

Comment: @Skywave на скрине видно же.

Comment: Заголовки можно [добавить веб-сервером](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11736804/apache-add-header-to-request-according-to-different-domain#11737187)

Comment: @TotalPusher у меня на сервере стоит `nginx` `apach` медленный, мне хостер предложил перейти на `apach` и предуведомлял что будет нагрузки и низкая скорость работы

Comment: Nginx также умеет [добавлять заголовки](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_headers_module.html#add_header)

Answer (score 1):

Решил эту проблему, друзья почему то не кто не напомнил мне об `http` оказывается нужна защищенный протокол т,е `https` и в начальный файл `index.php` заголовки:

```
header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');
header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET, POST');
header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers: X-Requested-With");
```