# Как настроить отправку post через axios на php - CORS ругается

Tags: php, vue.js, axios, cors

Аналогичная проблема, как у коллеги из [поста](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1010195/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%bd%d0%b0%d1%81%d1%82%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b8%d1%82-php-%d0%bd%d0%b0-cors/1381568#1381568). Только `front` у меня [vue.js](/questions/tagged/vue.js) (2.0) + [axios](/questions/tagged/axios). Шлю `post` на свой же сервер, даже в ту же папку на `*.php` скрипт. Домен у меня настроен на `https` - а [axios](/questions/tagged/axios) упорно сообщает `net::ERR_NAME_NOT_RESOLVED` (это под `Chrome`). В `Firefox` сообщение более вежливое, но суть не меняется - отсылка к [cors](/questions/tagged/cors) и все тут. Как это чудо побороть?

Также я попробовал в этом принимающий файл `php-скрипта` добавить указанные в вышеуказанном посте `header-ы`:

```
header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');
header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET, POST');
header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers: X-Requested-With");
```

но ситуация аналогична:

> isAxiosError.js:10 POST XXXXXX.RU/XXXXXXXXXXXXXX/review.php net::ERR_NAME_NOT_RESOLVED

Другого файла php для headers как бы нет...все остальное html/js.

Vue.js часть - вызов:

```js
async sendReview (boxId) {
    let strPath = window.location.href;
    let arrPath = strPath.split('.');
    let phpServer = arrPath[0] + arrPath[1] + '.php';
    try {
        let response = await axios.post( phpServer, boxId, this.pickinteriReview );
    } catch(e) {
        this.errors.push = e;
    }
}
```

Самый примитив "сервера" на .php - просто начало отладки:

```php
<?php
header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");
header("Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8");
header("Access-Control-Allow-Methods: OPTIONS,GET,POST,PUT,DELETE");
header("Access-Control-Max-Age: 3600");
header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Content-Type, Access-Control-Allow-Headers, Authorization, X-Requested-With");

return [ 'code' => '200', 'message' => 'OK' ];
```

Comment: let response = await axios.post( phpServer, this.pickinteriReview, postHeader ); - где в postHeader все заголовки и указание mode: 'no-cors' - также ничего не помог.

Comment: ERR_NAME_NOT_RESOLVED означает что ваш ПК не может получить IP адрес по имени домена. Если у вас локальный домен, то пропишите его адрес в hosts, если удаленный - то пропингуйте и проверьте что DNS работает, либо используйте nslookup.

Comment: @DanielProtopopov Похоже, Вы правы. Но домен на сервере; в одной папке лежит и html и js и php - и имя к "серверу" определяется по адресу js-скрипта, только с заменой расширения на php. Вручную он открывает браузер (пустая страница, но не 404). А пробую после Вашего совета проверить ответ сервера - один сервис отдает "Что-то пошло не так", другой корректно 500 ошибку.  Тогда непонятно,  в чем серверная проблема хостинга

Comment: если что, то в пхп ответ отдают с помощью `echo json_encode([....])` а не `return [...]`.

Comment: @teran спасибо, буду иметь ввиду. Там вообще у меня для тестов остался только header() с кодом ответа сервера.. но, в любом случае, спасибо.

Answer (score 0):

В итоге, не уверен, что это полностью вылечило проблему, но в любом случае у меня решение для "взаимодействия" HTTP POST-запроса и моего тестового сервера работает.
Фрагмент из vue.js-части:

```
        async sendReview (pickinteriReview) {
            let phpServerPath = window.location.origin + '/wp-content/plugins/tcapr/api/tcapr-server.php';
            let postHeader = {
                method: 'POST',
                mode: 'no-cors',
                headers: {
                    'Accept': 'application/json',
                    'WithCredentials': true,
                    'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*',
                    'Content-Type': 'application/json; charset=UTF-8',
                    'Access-Control-Allow-Methods': 'OPTIONS,GET,POST,PUT,DELETE',
                    'Access-Control-Allow-Headers': 'Content-Type, Access-Control-Allow-Headers, Authorization, X-Requested-With',
                    'Authorization': ''
                },
                withCredentials: true,
                credentials: 'same-origin',
            };
            try {
                this.info = await axios.post( phpServerPath, pickinteriReview, postHeader );
            } catch(e) {
                this.errors.push = e;
            }
        }
```

Ну а на приемной php-стороне

```
$obj =  json_decode($_POST, false);

$code = 200;
$text = 'OK';

$answer = ['code' => $code, 'message' => $text];
echo json_encode($answer);
```

Обратно ответ получаю в виде объектов **data** (для данного примера ответа это data.code = 200, data.message = "OK") и **headers** с кучей всего:
content-encoding:"br"
content-length:"31"
content-type:"text/html; charset=UTF-8"
date:"Mon, 14 Feb 2022 08:45:51 GMT"
server:"LiteSpeed"
vary:"Accept-Encoding"
x-powered-by:"PHP/7.3.33"
request:XMLHttpRequest
status:200
statusText:""

**В открытом вопросе - не передающиеся параметры** от axios (то есть post-дата). Контроль $_POST на стороне "сервера" показывает, что он пуст, соответственно и декодированная строка $obj также. Проверка отправляемых данных - Ок.

Answer (score 0):

Сам себе Буратино. Возможно, еще кому-то пригодится такое наблюдение - "Метод отправки формы по POST, и HTTP POST запрос axios вещи разные, хоть и имеют одинаковое слово".
Короче, вот сторона "сервера" для приема данных от запроса, и на этом данный вопрос закрываю:

```
header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");
header("Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8");
header("Access-Control-Allow-Methods: OPTIONS,GET,POST,PUT,DELETE");
header("Access-Control-Max-Age: 3600");
header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Content-Type, Access-Control-Allow-Headers, Authorization, X-Requested-With");

$method = $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'];
if ( 'POST' === $method ) {
    $code = 200;
    $text = 'OK';
    if ( array_key_exists('HTTP_X_HTTP_METHOD', $_SERVER) ) {
        $method = $_SERVER['HTTP_X_HTTP_METHOD'];
    }
    $arrParams = json_decode(file_get_contents('php://input'), true);   // parameters for  PUT, PATCH, POST requests
} else {
    $code = 405;
    $text = 'Method Not Allowed';
    $arrParams = null;
}
        
$answer = ['code' => $code, 'message' => $text . ': ' . $method];
echo json_encode($answer);
```

P.S. В данном случае мне интересен только POST, поэтому простой if. А так можно было бы сделать (это уже фрагмент из моего же кода, что самое обидное!) полную проверку:

```
        $this->method = $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'];
        if ($this->method == 'POST' && array_key_exists('HTTP_X_HTTP_METHOD', $_SERVER)) {
            $method = $_SERVER['HTTP_X_HTTP_METHOD'];
            if ('DELETE' === $method) {
                $this->method = 'DELETE';
            } else if ('HEAD' === $method) {
                $this->method = 'HEAD';
            } else if ('OPTIONS' === $method) {
                $this->method = 'OPTIONS';
            } else if ('PUT' === $method) {
                $this->method = 'PUT';
            } else if ('GET' === $method) {
                $this->method = 'GET';
            } else if ('POST' === $method) {
                $this->method = 'POST';
            } else if ('PATCH' === $method) {
                $this->method = 'PATCH';
            } else {
                throw new Exception("Unexpected Header");
            }
        }
```

и отрабатывать все типы запросов.

На этом всем спасибо, кто старался помочь *(особенно с ситуацией на сервере - в итоге DevOps-а призвали настроить нормально)*.